# read a string position

Tags: python, string

I'm struggling with a basic problem in python. I need to read a string at a certain position in order to modify it.

Example: for the string `'abcd'` I want to read the 3rd position (2nd really because you start from 0) and change it to the next letter of the alphabet, `'abdd'`. However, if string happened to be `'abrd'` that should change to `'absd'`, etc. So, I need to read and to write in a specific position and let everything else untouched; should be the simplest thing in the world, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question a bit. Are you looking to change string in **specific position**? For example, change the 3rd position regardless of the 3rd character is `r` or `c`. Or are you looking for **search the string for `r`**: if `r` changes 4th position, if `c` changes 3rd position and such.

Comment: What if the letter is 'z'?

Answer (score 2):

At its core the answer to your question is simple: use list slice syntax:

```
>>> string='abcd'
>>> print string[:2] + 'd' + string[3:]
abdd
```

If you can assume that it's safe to just increment the ordinal value of the string, then you can just do:

```
>>> string='abrd'
>>> string=string[:2] + chr(ord(string[2]) + 1) + string[3:]
```

Since it's not specified in your question, I'll assume that's what you need. You may find some rough patches if you wanted to loop from 'z' to 'a', or deal specially with different letter cases or unicode character sets.

If you *do* have a more sophisticated problem than just incrementing the `ord`, consider using a [translation table](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-functions)

Comment: for the last element substitution. I recommend using `string[3:]`. The `string` may not be 4 letters long all the time. Similiar, `string[0:2]` can be shorthanded to `string[:2]`.

Comment: That's great! Now I should be getting somewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aside from @kojiro answer. Another way of doing it is switching the *string* to *list* and join it back. For example:

```
S = 'abcd'
// Convert to list
L = list(S)
// Change 3rd position
L[3] = 'd'
// Join it back and print
print ''.join(L)
```

However, if you need to substitute different characters, you can define a *dictionary mapping* to ease the conversion process. For example:

```
// Define {a -> x} mapping.
M = {'c': 'd', 'r': 's'}
// Substitution
L[3] = M[L[3]]
```